# Setting screen time out on the lock screen

Tags: android, timeout, screen, lockscreen

I am trying to set the screen/display timeout on the lockscreen programmatically. I.e. the time from the last touch to screen off. I think it may be device dependent. I was able to change it on one phone (JB 4.2.2) with

```
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT, 30000);
```

but now this isn't working on my Nexus 5 (KK 4.4.2). No matter what I do, it seems to stay at 10s.

Any ideas? Is there a separate setting for the lockscreen?

Thanks!

Comment: Use putString and not putInt

Comment: @Mugen unfortunately that made no difference. putInt is also working just fine when not on the lock screen.

Answer (score -2):

If your app have device admin you can set time to lock [follow this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#getMaximumTimeToLock%28android.content.ComponentName%29)

```
public void setMaximumTimeToLock (ComponentName admin, long timeMs)
```

Comment: That is definitely not what I'm looking for. That makes the phone lock after a certain time in use...

Comment: This will work similar  to what you are looking , Thats way I mentioned if your app has device admin , even this will change setting screen timeout under brightness , please try before commenting..

Comment: From the documentation, setMaximumTimeToLock will automatically lock the phone after some time. I am looking to change the screen timeout after the phone has already been locked.